# GWT EXT Exception only in charts

Tags: javascript, gwt, extjs, charts, gwt-ext

I am trying to create a chart (graph) using the Line chart showcase code from GWT-EXT showcase as on http://www.gwt-ext.com/demo-charts/#lineChart
But facing the following error in the browser:

```
onModuleLoad() threw an exception
Exception while loading module com.client.LineChartSample. See Development Mode for details.

java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.ModuleSpace.onLoad(ModuleSpace.java:411)
at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.OophmSessionHandler.loadModule(OophmSessionHandler.java:200)
at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.BrowserChannelServer.processConnection(BrowserChannelServer.java:526)
at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.BrowserChannelServer.run(BrowserChannelServer.java:364)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: com.google.gwt.core.client.JavaScriptException: (TypeError) @com.gwtext.client.widgets.chart.yui.NumericAxis::create()([]): &apos;$wnd.YAHOO.widget&apos; is null or not an object
at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.BrowserChannelServer.invokeJavascript(BrowserChannelServer.java:249)
at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.ModuleSpaceOOPHM.doInvoke(ModuleSpaceOOPHM.java:136)
at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.ModuleSpace.invokeNative(ModuleSpace.java:576)
at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.ModuleSpace.invokeNativeObject(ModuleSpace.java:284)
at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.JavaScriptHost.invokeNativeObject(JavaScriptHost.java:91)
at com.gwtext.client.widgets.chart.yui.NumericAxis.create(NumericAxis.java)
at com.gwtext.client.widgets.chart.yui.Axis.<init>(Axis.java:37)
at com.gwtext.client.widgets.chart.yui.NumericAxis.<init>(NumericAxis.java:33)
at com.client.LineChartSample.onModuleLoad(LineChartSample.java:66)
... 9 more
```

And following error in the development mode of Eclipse IDE `[ERROR] [linechartsample] - Failed to load module 'linechartsample' from user agent 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/35.0.1916.153 Safari/537.36' at 127.0.0.1:54415`
I have tried the other showcase codes of simple form, button etc. from the showcase which run without any problem. What could be the possible reason for this?

Comment: You happened to have some own code, too? Stacktrace without the code is not enough clear about being able to answer nor see what's wrong.

Comment: well, that `&apos;` is a feature of html5 and according to here (http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?108748-HTML5-in-Ext-GWT) it is not supported with gwt-ext. How you then got that apos there is another issue and more clear with code in hand.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got the answer.. I hadn't inherited an important module...
The same code started working after adding the line :

```
<inherits name="com.gwtext.Charts" />
```

to the gwt.xml file...
The rest all remain the same.